# How to force a BatchWriteItem failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy, amazon-dynamodb, integration-testing, spock

I'm currently writing integration tests for my `BatchWriteItem` logic using Spock/Groovy. I'm running a docker container which spins up a real DynamoDb table for this same purpose.

This is my logic in Java for `BatchWriteItems`

```
public Promise<Boolean> createItemsInBatch(ClientKey clientKey, String accountId, List<SrItems> srItems) {
        List<Item> items = srItems.stream()
                .map(srItem -> createItemFromSrItem(clientKey, createItemRef(srItem.getId(), accountId), srItem))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<List<Item>> batchItems = Lists.partition(items, 25);

        var promises = batchItems.stream().map(itemsList -> Blocking.get(() -> {
            TableWriteItems tableWriteItems = new TableWriteItems(table.getTableName());
            tableWriteItems.withItemsToPut(itemsList);
            BatchWriteItemOutcome outcome = dynamoDB.batchWriteItem(tableWriteItems);
            return outcome.getUnprocessedItems().values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        })).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ParallelPromises.yieldAll(promises).map((List<? extends ExecResult<List<WriteRequest>>> results) -> {
            if(results.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                results.stream().map(Result::getValue).flatMap(Collection::stream).forEach(failure -> {
                    var failedItem = failure.getPutRequest().getItem();
                    logger.error(append("item", failedItem), "Failed to batch write item");
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is my current implementation for the test (**happy path**)

```
@Unroll
    def "createItemsInBatch - #description"(description, srItemsList, createResult) {
        given:
        def dynamoItemService = new DynamoItemService(realTable, amazonDynamoDBClient1) //passing the table running in the docker image + the dynamo client associated

        when:
        def promised = ExecHarness.yieldSingle {
            dynamoItemService.createItemsInBatch(CLIENT_KEY, 'account-id', srItemsList as List<SrItem>)
        }

        then:
        promised.success == createResult

        where:
        description                                        |  srItemsList          | createResult
        "single batch req not reaching batch size limit"   |  srItems(10)          | true
        "double batch req reaching batch size limit"       |  srItems(25)          | true
        "triple batch req reaching batch size limit"       |  srItems(51)          | true
    }
```

For context:

- `srItems()` is a function that just creates a bunch of different items to be injected in the service for the BatchWriteItem request

Want I want now is to be able to test the **unhappy path** of my logic, i.e. get some `UnprocessedItems` from my outcome, testing the below code is actually doing its job

```
BatchWriteItemOutcome outcome = dynamoDB.batchWriteItem(tableWriteItems);
            return outcome.getUnprocessedItems().values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to do actually, we can force throttling on your DynamoDB table which will result in `UnprocessedItems`....

Configure your table to have 1WCU and disable auto-scaling. Now run your BatchWriteItem in batches of 25 for a couple of seconds and DynamoDB will begin to throttle requests, which will return the throttled items in  the `UnprocessedItems` response, testing your unhappy path.

Comment: I set up the table with `.withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(5L, 5L));` and even if I put it to the minimum (1L) it still handles me inserting around 5000 items in batches of 25

Comment: DynamoDB has the idea if burst capacity, where it banks unused capacity for 300 seconds. You have to write long enough to deplete the burst tokens for it to throttle. 1 WCU is only capable of writing 1 item per second, so it will definitely throttle if doing batches of 25 once burst is empty.